Optimization of relative error vs optimization on log scale
I am currently training a model to predict house sales prices, $P$, as a function of a set of characteristics $\textbf{x}$. The model I have chosen is a log-specified regression model of the form:
\begin{align}
\ln(P) = f(\textbf{x}) \ \ \ (1)
\end{align}
which I fit with ordinary least squares.
Now for my application it is often not the absolute error, but rather the relative error that is important. Using concrete error measures, I am e.g. often more interested in a model that does well measured by the mean absolute relative error
\begin{align}
\varepsilon_{\text{rel}} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j} \| P_{j} - \hat{P} \|/P_{j} \ \ \ (2)
\end{align}
as opposed to the more standard mean absolute error
\begin{align}
\varepsilon = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j} \| P_{j} - \hat{P} \| \ \ \ (3)
\end{align}
My question is the following: In what sense can optimization on the log-scale be considered equivalent to minimization of the relative error of the model?
To elaborate a bit on what has led to me to asking this question, consider the following simple example. Assume I had only two price data points $P_{1} = 10, P_{2} = 100$ and consider the simplest model, which just uses the average of the data points as the model prediction. It is immediately clear that using a log-transformation reduces the overall relative error as $\hat{P}_{\text{ln}} = \exp((\ln(100) + \ln(10))/2) \approx 32$ and $\hat{P} = (100 + 10)/2 = 55$, where the former has a lower mean absolute relative error as measured by (2).
Going back to my original question, is there a more precise mathematical way of expressing the reasoning above? My own attempt is the following. Assume that one trains a log-specified regression model of the form given in (1). This corresponds to minimizing a least-squares cost of the form:
\begin{align}
C = \sum_{j}(\ln(P_{j}) – f(\textbf{x}_{j}))^2
\end{align}
Now, given that the fitted function comes close to $\ln(P_{j})$ we may write $f(\textbf{x}_{j}) = \ln(P_{j} + \Delta P)$, where $\Delta P$ is some small number. To first order we then find
\begin{align}
C = \sum_{j}(\ln(P_{j}) –  \ln(P_{j} + \Delta P))^2 = \sum_{j}(\ln((P_{j} + \Delta P )/P_{j}))^2 = \sum_{j}(\ln((1 + \Delta P/P_{j}))^2 \approx \sum_{j}(\Delta P/P_{j})^2.
\end{align}
which shows that to first-order an optimization of prices on the log-scale is equivalent to the optimization of the relative error. Does the above reasoning make sense, or is there a simpler and more elegant that expresses what I am trying to say?
Thanks a lot

Your relative error is often called a Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE). I would very much recommend What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)? and possibly Kolassa (2020). In addition, What is the best point forecast for lognormally distributed data? may be helpful, especially of course the section on the MAPE. I would very much encourage you to think it terms of predictive densities and summarizing them.
